# Show ellipsis(...) when data exceeds the column width in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable with Angular (https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/). Currently, my text gets cut when the data exceeds the column width. So, I want to show ellipsis and moreover, when user hovers over the ellipsis or the data, it should show the full details.
Any help would be appreciated.
[trimmed text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV0W0.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as long as it's the same DOM structure in the example link you provided just add this CSS somewhere;

```
.datatable-body-cell-label {
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```